# Facebook post on page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm using [Facebook SDK 6](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests.html) and Graph API to publish data from app (ASP.NET) to the [page](http://www.facebook.com/TfdTest).

Firstly, my app (website) get access token using server flow as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).
Next, it use this token to publish some text in my page:

```
    Dim fb = New FacebookClient(accessToken)
    Dim o As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    o.Add("message", "some text...")
    Dim result = fb.Post("/TfdTest/feed", o)
```

To test it, I browse my website. I allow my site change my facebook page and give permissions (publish_stream, manage_pages). The problem is that final feed appears in "Recent Posts by Others" section:

[image]

**How can I post feed from page name, not from myself???**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to use Graph API on behalf of a Page, you need to get Page access token - see here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

1. Authenticate the user and request the **manage_pages** permission
2. Get the list of pages the user manages using token from (1) - https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
3. Parse the list and get the PAGE token - and use it to post to the feed.

Comment: as for api version v2.4, the correct permissions for this are  manage_pages and publish_pages.